# json data is being stored as a single row

Tags: python, json, pandas, mongodb

```
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient


client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['zomato_db']
collection_zomato = db['zomatores']


 with open('E:\\DAPProject\\Datasets\\ZOMATORES.json') as f:
 file_data = json.load(f)


  collection_zomato.insert_one(file_data)
  client.close()
```

When I try to store the data in mongodb it gets stored as a single row.
How to store it as multiple rows?[Output DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmy84.png)

Comment: how is the schema of your json file ?..can you add it ?

Answer (score 0):

try the insertMany() method

```
db.collection.insertMany(
   [ <document 1> , <document 2>, ... ],
   {
      writeConcern: <document>,
      ordered: <boolean>
   }
)
```

This is the documentation in the mongodb site: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/